# Rss reader issue, on dropdown display next

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, rss, visual-studio-2015

Ok so I am very new to C# and retrieved a piece of code to display rss software update information from a site to my windows program. I noticed that one of the nodes had the description I needed displayed as  so I changed the code a bit to try and gather this information; however, when doing this I broke the dropdown box feature, tried to fix it myself but couldn't figure out what went wrong.

So what happens is on the form_load event it should load the rss page into my display box then if I select a different patch note from the dropdown box it should change based on what I selected. Right now it only changes the bottom text link and not the main window displaying the  information.

This is the code itself. I commented out their old line and added mine for displaying .

```
String[,] rssData = null;

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TitlesBox.Items.Clear();
    rssData = getRssData(ChannelTextBox.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i < rssData.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (rssData[i, 0] != null)
        {
            TitlesBox.Items.Add(rssData[i, 0]);
        }
        TitlesBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}

private String[,] getRssData(String channel)
{
    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(channel);
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

    Stream rssStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
    XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();

    rssDoc.Load(rssStream);
    XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("//rss/channel/item");

    XmlNamespaceManager nMger = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssDoc.NameTable);
    nMger.AddNamespace("content", rssDoc.DocumentElement.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("content"));

    String[,] tempRssData = new String[100, 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < rssItems.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlNode rssNode;

        rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("title");
        if (rssNode != null)
        {
            tempRssData[i, 0] = rssNode.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            tempRssData[i, 0] = "";
        }

        rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("content:encoded", nMger);
        //rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("description");
        if (rssNode != null)
        {
            tempRssData[i, 1] = rssNode.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            tempRssData[i, 1] = "";
        }

        rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link");
        if (rssNode != null)
        {
            tempRssData[i, 2] = rssNode.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            tempRssData[i, 2] = "";
        }
    }
    return tempRssData;
}

private void TitlesBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 1] != null)
        OutputBox.DocumentText = rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 1];
    if (rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 2] != null)
        linkLabel.Text = "GoTo: " + rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 0];
}

private void linkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 2] != null)
        Process.Start(rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 2]);
}
```

Comment: The code isn't finding the tag "content:encoded" so rssNode is null.  Need to see the XML to provide a fix.

Comment: Its finding it because its displaying it. unless you mean the tag for the dropdown bug isn't finding it because that's what it seems like. I still need a fix on this.

Comment: It wasn't clear that new code displayed results.  Maybe only one item is being returned and that is why the drop down isn't working.  Original code returned more than one result.

Comment: Yea new code displays the results of the first feed but then when selecting another feed from the dropdown it does not display it. It does gather the title and url but does not display the description or change it in the box below the dropdown box

Comment: Usually issues like this is due to the control update event not recognizing the binding data has changed.  The usual trick is to set the control data to null and then back to the new data.   This will force an update event.

Comment: Has something do do with TitlesBox_SelectedIndexChanged when I select a new item in the dropdown box the linkLabel changes like it should but the OutputBox does not. So I checked the line which shows the OutputBox change and see it = rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 1]; I check that out in the above code and it looks right to me but im not sure

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem. The problem was here.

```
private void TitlesBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 1] != null)
            OutputBox.DocumentText = rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 1];
        if (rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 2] != null)
            linkLabel.Text = "GoTo: " + rssData[TitlesBox.SelectedIndex, 0];
    }
```

OutputBox was a RichTextBox which would not accept the change so I changed it to a WebBrowser and now it is working. Was in the design itself.

Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The selected index count be set to -1 when you are changing the data in the box.  So I would test for >= 0.  I would use sender instead of assuming the object is the TitlesBox.  See code below.

```css
        private void TitlesBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
            if (box.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                OutputBox.DocumentText = ((List<string>)(box.Items[box.SelectedIndex]))[1];
                linkLabel.Text = "GoTo: " + ((List<string>)(box.Items[box.SelectedIndex]))[0];
            }
 
        }
​
```